# Cannot visit ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, scope

I have this scope in my `Answer` model

```
scope :court, where(joins(:case))
```

When I use the scope in Console I got this error

```
> Answer.court
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `answers` INNER JOIN `cases` ON `cases`.`answer_id` = `answers`.`id`
TypeError: Cannot visit ActiveRecord::Relation
```

so what's this error really mean?, Is the scope syntax is wrong although the SQL query is right??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the scope should be defined as

```
scope :court, joins(:case)
```